# Create Sublime Snippet that uses dynamic value extracted from the code?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Say I have started writing JavaScript like this:

```
function User() {

}

User.prototype.save = function(){

};
```

Is it possible to create a Sublime Text snippet that will generate a function like this:

```
User.prototype.<name> = function(){
  | // cursor after you enter name and press tab
};
```

Basically, I would type `p` or some keyboard shortcut, and it would figure out "oh, you want to create a new method on the `User.prototype`, here you go." Is that possible? Basically, it would rip out the `User` name from the function above somehow?

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[${1:Constructor}.prototype.${2:name} = function(){
  $0
};]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>p</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Instead of `Constructor` in that snippet, is there a way to make that a dynamic value, without having to type it in?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without writing a plugin. Snippets are pretty self contained so can't read the rest of the file they're inserted into